# How do i make meshes separate from eachother?

Tags: mesh

All parts work as their own in edit mode, count as one in object mode. Looking to make them all separate.
[image: Only one cube showing up in "scene" top right, can't make an indentation without having them separate]

Comment: In Edit Mode select everything "A" then press "P" and Loose Parts from the drop down menu.

Comment: This worked, but it makes all the objects (except the one active in the picture) uneditable and i can't seem to bring it back without loading.

Comment: Glad to hear it... Did you go into Object Mode to select a loose part?
 Maybe upload your .blend file using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/